# How to get facebook user ID or name without Facebook Application

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on web app which is NOT a Facebook Application.
I want to get current logged user's ID (I'm not sure if this is the right expression, I mean facebook.com/**userid** ) or user's name using Javascript.

Please if you don't know how to do it or if you don't have any suggestion what should help me,  **don't comment** , thanks.
How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by current logged-in user- in facebook or in your app?\

Comment: If I'm logged to Facebook and I vist my site, I want to see my id there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** get the details (facebook id etc.) of the currently logged-in facebook user without using an app.

To query for the current user, you'll have to query for the `/me` and that requires an active access token which you can only get when the user authorizes an app!